# Want to repeat the contents of a title tag into the html document itself

Tags: php, html, extract

My website has millions of pages and all of them are static html (actually .shtml, but I have set them up in the server to parse as .shtml while still displaying as .html). I can use Includes as well as php scripts within my html file. 
I use include statements like the following within my current pages:

```
<!--#include virtual="somefilename.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="somefilename.php"-->
```

I am trying to add the Facebook social tag on all my .html pages:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Page Title" />
```

I need the same values for this tag as exists between `<title></title>` tag on the same page.

So, I need to extract the data between `<title>My Page Title</title>` tag and print them within `<meta property="og:title" content="My Page Title" />` for each page.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: please tell us if you are thinking of a "one time script" to update all existing pages, or something else.

Comment: Not a one time script to update all existing page. But a script which loads on run time, grabs content between <title></title> and pastes it in <meta property="og:title" content="My Page Title" /> within the same html file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an HTML parser such as [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) to find the `<title>` tags with [`getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), then output what you need, like so:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( '<title>My Page Title</title>'); 
// However you read in your HTML file, could even do:
// $doc->loadHTMLFile( '/my/server/root/index.html');

foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'title') as $title) {
    echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . $title->textContents . '" />';
}
```

You'd use this as a script to load up all of your HTML pages. So, you would put this in a PHP file on your server, and run it once. You would need to add a wrapper to it so it knows where all of your HTML files are. You can use something like this:

```
foreach( glob( '*.html') as $filename) {
    // The above code, which you can now use $doc->loadHTMLFile( $filename);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I am confused. Where do I add the above line of code? In the html file itself or in a php script and call it within. Can you please be more specific, as I am a pretty amateur here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, but I still don't get it properly. I understand that I put the 1st part of the code in a php script. But what do I add to each individual html file to reference or print the output.

Comment: @user - Nothing - You use this script to modify all of your HTML files. This script is meant to read in your HTML files, add what you need, and write the HTML file back.